# How to align the text middle of BUTTON

Tags: html, css

Can you anyone please help me to code this below one

This is my current code

```
<div id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn"><span>Log in</span></div>
```

div tag have loginBtn class and span tag having "log in" text in html page

```
.loginBtn {
    background:url(images/loginBtn-center.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    margin:20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px #5e5d5b;
}
```

I created the button using 1px image. Now i am unable to place the "log in" text middle of the image can any one help me complete the code

text is displaying left top corner. Please help me.

Comment: Adding text-align: center; should work in your css.

Comment: Use `button.style.padding = '0px'`

Answer (score 36):

You can use `text-align: center; line-height: 65px;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QvbxB/)

CSS

```
.loginBtn {
    background:url(images/loginBtn-center.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    margin:20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px #5e5d5b;
    text-align: center;  <--------- Here
    line-height: 65px;   <--------- Here
}
```

Comment: does not work for multiple lines text

Answer (score 30):

This is more predictable then "line-height"

```css
.loginBtn {
    background:url(images/loginBtn-center.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    margin:20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px #5e5d5b;
}

.loginBtn span {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn"><span>Log in</span></div>
```

## EDIT (2018): use flexbox

```
.loginBtn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometime it is fixed by the Padding .. if you can play with that, then, it should fix your problem

```
<style type=text/css>

YourbuttonByID {Padding: 20px 80px; "for example" padding-left:50px; 
 padding-right:30px "to fix the text in the middle 
 without interfering with the text itself"}

</style>
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Padding like: Hope this one can help you.

```
.loginButton {
    background:url(images/loginBtn-center.jpg) repeat-x;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    margin:20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px #5e5d5b;
    <!--Using padding to align text in box or image-->
    padding: 3px 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
margin: auto;
```